# Why is scroll-margin not working in Nuxt?

Tags: css, nuxt.js

I am working in a Nuxt app and using CSS based smooth scrolling to anchor links. The smooth scroll itself works but the `scroll-margin` property is achieving nothing... it is seemingly completely ignored. The exact same code works fine outside of the Nuxt app so I wonder whether it is something to do with Nuxt.

Slimmed down version of the code is as follows and I have also created [a (working) non-Nuxt codepen to show the code in action](https://codepen.io/andrewCodepens/pen/VwdjXxL) outside of Nuxt.

For the sake of clarity, I want to use CSS only to achieve smooth scrolling with a scroll margin in Nuxt. I do not want to use JavaScript or built in Vue / Nuxt features. If I have to I will but, at the very least, I'd like to know why `scroll-margin` is not doing anything.

HTML

```
<main>
    <header>Fixed header</header>

    <section><a href="#scroll-section">Click this link to scroll to a section further down the page and show the targeted state</a>. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem iste fuga quae fugit molestiae accusamus dolorum ea doloremque veritatis totam! Eum exercitationem nostrum nam doloribus, blanditiis quidem inventore perspiciatis ullam?</section>
    
    <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum architecto explicabo accusamus! Ab fuga fugiat hic recusandae, quo, dignissimos tempore velit aliquam facere, accusamus explicabo pariatur at enim modi doloremque.</section>

    <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipisicing elit. Quidem iste fuga quae fugit molestiae accusamus dolorum ea doloremque veritatis totam! Eum exercitationem nostrum nam doloribus, blanditiis quidem inventore perspiciatis ullam?</section>

    <section id="scroll-section"> <strong class="show-on-target">Check out the space between this block and the header  The block is clear of the header thanks to the <code>scroll-margin</code> property. The block was blue before you clicked the link and this text wasn't here either.</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum architecto explicabo accusamus! Ab fuga fugiat hic recusandae, quo, dignissimos tempore velit aliquam facere, accusamus explicabo pariatur at enim modi doloremque.</section>

    <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum architecto explicabo accusamus! Ab fuga fugiat hic recusandae, quo, dignissimos tempore velit aliquam facere, accusamus explicabo pariatur at enim modi doloremque.</section>

    <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipisicing elit. Quidem iste fuga quae fugit molestiae accusamus dolorum ea doloremque veritatis totam! Eum exercitationem nostrum nam doloribus, blanditiis quidem inventore perspiciatis ullam?</section>
</main>
```

SCSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: helvetica;
    margin-inline: 0;
    line-height:1.5;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    inset-block-start: 0;
    inset-inline-start: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3rem;
    background: #ed6a5a;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

section {
    background: #9bc1bc;    
    padding: 50px 30px;
    
    &:nth-child(2n) {
        background: #f4f1bb;
    }
    
    &:first-of-type {
        padding-block-start: 20vh;
    }
}

strong {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

code {
    font-family: monospace;
}

:target {
    scroll-margin: 5rem;
    background: #F2D7EE;
    
    .show-on-target {
        display: block;
        margin-block-end: 20px;
    }
}

.show-on-target {
    display: none;
}
```

**What I tried:**

Using the code above to create a CSS-only smooth-scroll including a scroll-margin. I also tried tweaking the code above to use `section`, `[id]`, `section[id]` and `#myAnchor` in place of `:target` but to no avail.

**What I was expecting:**

Page to scroll smoothly to the anchor leaving a 5 rem margin above it.

**What actually happens:**

Page scrolls smoothly to the anchor but with no margin above it

Comment: I've answered plenty of those questions before. Please give some of them a read: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+scroll Yours will probably have a solution in there (depending on your Nuxt version, other packages, syntax etc...).

Comment: thanks, @kissu , but none of those seem to be pure css solutions or explain why scroll-margin does not work. I found various related questions / answers (probably including yours) but nothing I've found answers these specific questions.

Comment: There are some pure CSS solutions that are solving exactly your use-case. And there can be several solutions for that one, hence why I recommend one of my already-posted answers.

Comment: I've been through all of those posts looking for an answer as to why scroll-margin is not working inside Nuxt when it works elsewhere. I see no explanation. If you know the answer please post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I searched for a solution to this problem, but like you, I couldn't find anything about it. So, I went back to the Nuxt documentation and discovered that Nuxt overwrites the Vue Scroll Behavior.

To fix the issue, I created a new file at `/app/router.options.ts` and added some lines of code. It worked perfectly for me. Here's the code I used:

```
import type { RouterConfig } from "@nuxt/schema";

export default <RouterConfig>{
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to && to.hash) {
      return {
        el: to.hash,
        top: 81, // Add here the padding or margin top that you want
        behavior: "smooth",
      };
    } else {
      return { top: 0, left: 0, behavior: "smooth" };
    }
  },
};
```

I hope that will help you too.

Comment: thanks. you probably already know but as others reading this may not... scroll-margin not working was a bug that was resolved as part of the v2.16 update. v.2.16 had breaking changes in it though so @FahDev's solution is perfect for projects using < v.2.16